# Is it possible to use one application for several likes?

Tags: facebook

I have a photoalbum where I'd like to allow several photos to be liked by facebook users. 
For example, I have a photoalbum, there are 5 photos. I would like something like this:

- a.jpg (12 people like it)
- b.jpg (23 people like it)
- c.jpg (3 people like it)

Is possible to do with single registred application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this depending on your application.

If you do not authenticate users in your app, then you have generate URLs for each image and then insert like buttons for each image. For example, you can create a page in your app called photo.php which takes an ID and displays that image. You can then add like buttons for each image with the URL set to the photo URL in your app:

```
<div class="fb-like" 
    data-href="http://apps.facebook.com/myapplication/photo.php?id=1" 
    data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" 
    data-share="false">
</div>

<div class="fb-like" 
    data-href="http://apps.facebook.com/myapplication/photo.php?id=2" 
    data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" 
    data-share="false">
</div>

<div class="fb-like" 
    data-href="http://apps.facebook.com/myapplication/photo.php?id=3" 
    data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" 
    data-share="false">
</div>
```

If the images are within a Facebook photo album, then the likes that you get via these buttons will not count towards the likes the photos get in the Facebook photo album. Also, if you want nice details to be displayed in the users timeline for each of the likes then you should be sure to include the relevant Open Graph meta tags on the photo.php page. You can dynamically generate these from the photo ID. Without authentication, there is no way to generate a Facebook like button for a Facebook object such as a photo.

If you are authenticating users, then you can do it differently - you can make it so that the likes that are received in the application actually count towards the likes that the photos have in the Facebook photo album. You will need the "publish_actions" permission as well as "publish_stream". With jQuery you can bind an event similar to below to your own custom like button:

```
$('#LikePhoto1').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_OBJECT_ID/likes?method=POST&format=json&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN',
       success: function(res) {
        alert('liked');
        }
    });
});
```

You will need to find the PHOTO_OBJECT_ID which relates to that photo within that album - I recommend using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to do this. Also, you will need to set the ACCESS_TOKEN in the URL to the current authenticated user's access token.

Because this is a custom like button, it doesn't display the number of likes etc - you will need to query this from the Graph API using the URL https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_OBJECT_ID/likes?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN